# Общие разделы для 2-х инфоблоков

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, cms, раздел

Есть сайт [w3layouts](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/), [demo](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/30-04-2020/publication-liberty-demo_Free/1014263797/web/index.html?_ga=2.10170935.389158234.1643541675-1945748479.1640607858).
На этом сайте есть инфоблок `Topics` с разделами `Market Tips, Sports, Techniques`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть также инфоблок `Fifthposts` с теми же разделами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В админке 1C Bitrix это выглядит следующим образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. существуют инфоблоки `Topics, Fifthposts`(`Fifthposts` я создам - не создал, потому что не знаю буду ли задавать свойства для него).

Разделы `Topics`-а

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вставить эти же разделы в инфоблок `Fifthposts`, выделив для разделов отдельную сущность (или каким-нибудь образом, но чтобы не вводить те же самые разделы для инфоблока `Fifthposts`)?

Comment: Разделы инфоблоков существуют только для конкретного инфоблока. Единственно, что можно сделать - это ловить события редактирования\создания разделов в одном инфоблоке и на этом событии соответственно изменять второй инфоблок. В итоге у тебя все равно будут одинаковые по названию разделы.

Comment: Если отойти от концепции разделов, то можно создать третий инфоблок-словарь, содержащий некие элементы. В первых двух инфоблоках создать пользовательское свойство, указывающее на этот инфоблок и подцеплять элементы из него.

Answer (score 0):

Разделы, так же как и элементы, могут принадлежать только одному инфоблоку. Для решения данной задачи можно создать отдельный инфоблок для списка рубрик и добавить привязку к элементам этого инфоблока в виде пользовательского поля во все другие инфоблоки. Для навигации по этим рубрикам внутри каждого инфоблока можно сделать предустановленные фильтры.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).